# Newlines resolved as =0A in Sendgrid X-SMTPAPI header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid to send email to a mailing list, using the X-SMTPAPI header to specify the multiple recipients. From the [Sendgrid documentation](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/) "Headers must be wrapped to keep the line length under 72."

I am using the ActionMailer to send emails, and setting the X-SMTPAPI header using the `headers` method. To keep lines less than 72 characters, I have tried replacing each comma with a comma+newline+space. For example,

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = {
        :to => ['user1@example.com','user2@example.com','user3@example.com','user4@example.com','user5@example.com','user6@example.com']
}.to_json.gsub(',',",\n ")
```

Instead of getting newlines in my header, I am getting the following (from the log file)

```
X-SMTPAPI: {"to":["user1@example.com",=0A "user2@example.com",=0A "user3@example.com",=0A "user4@example.com",=0A "user5@example.com",=0A "user6@example.com"]}
```

Note that the \n characters are being replaced with `=0A`. This sequence is rejected as invalid by the Sendgrid server.

Any ideas what I can do to get the proper newlines into the header?

Edit:
I tried adding a "puts headers" to see what is being set in the headers. Then is what I found

```
Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2013 18:21:36 -0400
Message-ID: <5169da701cd26_5343fe1776afc50749b4@saunders.mail>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-SMTPAPI: {"to":["user1@example.com",=0A "user2@example.com",=0A
 "user3@example.com",=0A "user4@example.com",=0A "user5@example.com",=0A
 "user6@example.com"]}
```

Note the newlines I am adding are still showing up as "=0A". But something appears to be adding wrapping on its own. Is this wrapping automatic, and sufficient to keep my header line length from exceeding the requirements?

Comment: and if you `puts headers["X-SMTPAPI"]` just after `to_json` it the output is the same?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. But I noticed that there is some line wrapping being applied, but not where I inserted it. See the edit above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActionMailer actually will handle folding and encoding the lines for you if you give it the proper spacing to do so. You should use `JSON.generate` to give it the spacing:

Ex.

```
headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = JSON.generate({
  :category => "welcome_email",
  :to => ['user1@example.com','user2@example.com','user3@example.com','user4@example.com','user5@example.com','user6@example.com']
}, :indent => ' ')
```

Which would result in:

```
X-SMTPAPI: { "category":"welcome_email", "to":[  "user1@example.com",
 "user2@example.com",  "user3@example.com",  "user4@example.com",  
 "user5@example.com",     "user6@example.com"]}
```

As you can see, when ActionMailer encounters whitespace, it will wrap things for you - no need for the usual `\r\n`.

Comment: You are correct. I had just figured that out while spelunking through the ActionMailer Mail::UnstructuredField class. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add that Sendgrid actually requires you to use this approach (spaces vs newlines) if using Rails and ActionMailer; if you embed newlines directly Sendgrid throws an error parsing the JSON but if you use spaces the ActionMaler will put it into a Sendgrid-friendly format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like characters in headers have to be encoded according to the rules of [RFC 2047 [14]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).
Accodingly to ASCII table `%0A` states for `\n`

Comment: Then how can I fold long header lines, if my newline characters are being encoded automatically?

Comment: @DaveIsaacs, i'm not sure, but you may try `...gsub(',',",\\n ")`

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't work. The `\\n` gets resolved as two individual characters: a \ and an n.

Comment: @DaveIsaacs, isn't it interpretated as new line later?.. bad(