# Invalid SMTPAPI Header - SendGrid

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid for an automated mailing system that I am developing.

Unfortunately I am getting this error out of nowhere, on random occasions, from time to time.

First I thought that I am exceeding the allowed 1000 chars line length, that was probably true, since after I've added "\r\n" in various HTML parts of the email, the error started occurring more rarely.

The SendGrid "Support Engineers" are completely impotent when it comes to solving this isse.

And still, this situation is very problematic for me, since it's one of the most crucial core feature of my system, and it must be solid and reliable.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear you've been running into trouble with the SMTPAPI and that support wasn't able to assist you.  You're probably right about hitting the 1000 character limit.  Depending what you're sending the email with, you might be able to add in some indenting space to solve the problem:

```
var SMTPAPIHeader = JSON.stringify(yourJSONobject, null, " ");
```

See this question for more details on that:

[Newlines resolved as =0A in Sendgrid X-SMTPAPI header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992281/newlines-resolved-as-0a-in-sendgrid-x-smtpapi-header)

Also, feel free to email community@sendgrid.com if you'd like some more help from our developer relations team.

Comment: Problem is that I am using it in t he PHP cli environment.
Any alternatives to this there?.

The support guys just told me to add "\r\n", which I already did, and yet when I output the headers using $mail->getHeadersJson(), in sublime it seems as if the whole header consists only of one - several lines.