# Limit line length when serializing with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, sendgrid

I'm integrating with SendGrid API and they state the following regarding SMTP headers:

> Headers must be wrapped to keep the line length under 72. By RFC 821 no line can be longer than 1,000, so if you are going to generate this string yourself it is a good idea to make sure that you wrap it.

They provide an example where, after generating a string deserialization of the JSON representation of the object, they break lines based on whitespaces using a regex.

Although that may work, I shared the same concerns expressed in this [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231110/serializing-json-tersely-with-a-max-line-length).

In my case, since I'm using JSON.NET I can't apply that solution, but I'm sure something similar should be possible in JSON.NET. However I haven't found how to do it yet.

Comment: Why would you put something large in the *header*, instead of the *body*?

Comment: They require this to be sent as a header called X-SMTPAPI. I guess the reason is you can send the same header to their SMTP and Web API endpoints. I'm actually using the SMTP one.

Comment: Why can't you with JSON.NET? How are you serializing? In most cases you get a string back anyhow so seems trivial to cut up into 72 char blocks?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Formatting = Formatting.Indented` of your `JsonSerializer`? This will automatically make short, single lines. Unless ofc the value of your properties are very big

Comment: @Lloyd yes, I could do after but it would be nicer to be done as part of the serialization process, so the serializer chooses when to split and when to keep. For instance, a property name with two words shouldn't be split, while its string value should be. If I can't do that, I'll "fall back" to do it against the serialized string as you said.

Comment: @BerndLinde yes, I tried that too, but the Json object is nested so the more levels, the less space. Also I can't guarantee that a property value won't be longer than those 72. Names, for instance, are set to 100 so they can be longer than that.

Comment: From all the documentation I have read regarding JSON.Net, there is no build in way of doing this. Unless your inherit and override their classes (creating future maintenance for yourself), the only option I can currently see is doing it post-serialization